# Isolated Azure Function with Option Pattern and Application settings

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

I want to use the option pattern in my Isolated Azure Function.
The way I have it implemented right now works when I run it locally with the local.settings.json
but not when deployed.

Is it possible to do this without Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("") ?

This is my local.settings.json. I have these settings for example in the azure portal as application settings

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
    
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
        "STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING": "",
        "STORAGE_FOLDER_NAME": "",
        "STORAGE_SHARE_NAME": ""
    }
}
```

This is my option class

```
public class ApplicationOptions
{
    public const string Values = "Values";

    public string STORAGE_SHARE_NAME { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string STORAGE_FOLDER_NAME { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

in my program.cs for example

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(ConfigureAppConfiguration)
            .ConfigureServices((builder, services) =>
            {
                AddConfigurationOptions(builder, services);
            })
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }

    private static void ConfigureAppConfiguration(HostBuilderContext hostingContext, IConfigurationBuilder config)
    {
        config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true);
        config.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true);
        config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }

    private static void AddConfigurationOptions(HostBuilderContext builder, IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _ = services.AddOptions<ApplicationOptions>()
            .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection(ApplicationOptions.Values))
            .ValidateDataAnnotations()
            .ValidateOnStart();
    }
```

Locally i can access the values like this.

```
    var settings = builder.Configuration
        .GetSection(ApplicationOptions.Values)
        .Get<ApplicationOptions>();

    var folderName = settings.STORAGE_FOLDER_NAME;
```

Comment: You can inject `IConfiguration` which will pick your environment variables. To use them in Azure, you need to add them to your Function deployment's configuration?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by Function deployment's configuration. 

For example the "STORAGE_SHARE_NAME", I have that in the local.settings.json as well as directly on the azure portal --> function app --> configuration --> application settings. Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("STORAGE_SHARE_NAME") will work with both, locally as well as on azure.

The way i described on the original post will only work locally with the local.settings.json not on azure.

Comment: I mean exactly Azure => Function app => Configuration => Application settings. I'm not sure you can use those in the options pattern, there is no section to get and `Bind` to your `ApplicationOptions`. This is why I suggested that you use `IConfiguration` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use Options pattern in isolated Function Apps, but you need to keep in mind that the configurations that your store under "Values" in your local.settings.json file cannot be hierarchical. You need to follow the official [conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#working-with-options-and-settings) as in in-process Function Apps. I also recommend you to follow the .NET naming conventions as well and don't use the C-like constant names (e.g. MySettings instead of MY_SETTING). Another improvement could be to choose a name for your options class that more closely indicate the purpose of the settings it contains. The main benefit of options pattern is the encapsulation and separation of concerns, after all.

To give you an example, your settings in local.settings.json should look like the following:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "AzureWebJobsStorageConnectionStringValue",
    "Storage:ConnectionString": "",
    "Storage:FolderName": "",
    "Storage:ShareName": ""
  }
}
```

The options class will look like the following:

```cs
public class StorageOptions
{
    public const string Storage = "Storage";

    public string ShareName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string FolderName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

To register your options in your Program.cs, you will need something like the following:

```cs
//...
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        //...
        services.AddOptions<StorageOptions>()
            .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
            {
                configuration.GetSection(StorageOptions.Storage).Bind(settings);
            });
       //...
    })
    .Build();
host.Run();
```

Now, you can easily access the options where needed, or in your Function. Just add a parameter of type IOptions to the constructor and extract its `.Value` and store it in a variable of type `StorageOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to ponits @Ivan Gechev Azure => Function app => Configuration => Application settings and chech the `local.settings.json` is present in the respect path .

[image]

```
 public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
     [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "listfiles")] HttpRequest req,
     ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
 {
     string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
     string settingsFilePath = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "local.settings.json");

     if (!File.Exists(settingsFilePath))
     {
         return new BadRequestObjectResult("local.settings.json not found.");
     }

     IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
         .SetBasePath(currentDirectory)
         .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
         .AddEnvironmentVariables()
         .Build();

     string connectionString = config["AzureWebJobsStorage"];
```

[image]